# Set The novalidate Attribute On SilverStripe 3 <form>?

Tags: forms, attributes, silverstripe

As I understand the SilverStripe 3 Form class, the only method available to set form attributes is setAttribute( String $name, String $value ).

But to set the novalidate attribute, there is only one parameter, novalidate.

How do I add the novalidate attribute to a form object?

Bob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `novalidate` attribute should work with or without a value. 
That is, the following will work the same:

```
<form novalidate>
    ...
</form>
```

And:

```
<form novalidate="novalidate">
    ...
</form>
```

So you can pass `novalidate` as both parameters for the `setAttribute()` function like so:

```
$form->setAttribute('novalidate', 'novalidate');
```

Comment: Good news/Bad news. Your explanation of setting the novalidate attribute worked just fine. The bad news is that it killed SS's validation, not the text bubble I was trying to get rid of! So my new question is at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18647516/eliminate-text-bubble-error-on-silverstripe-3-forms