# Eliminate Text Bubble Error On SilverStripe 3 Forms

Tags: forms, validation, silverstripe

For some reason I'm getting two different kinds of error messages on the same SS 3 form as shown in the referenced screenshot. How do I get rid of the text bubble style error message on the email field and have them all look like the error box on the name field?

Screenshot: http://d.pr/i/ThmL

Bob

Comment: The error message on the left is javascript validation, while the error message on the right is browser validation. The error on the right is occurring because the field is marked as an email, and you have not entered a valid email address. But javascript is not checking that fields are correctly filled in, it is only checking if required fields are empty. Are you using your own javascript validation, or letting Silverstripe set the javascript validation?

Comment: It's SS's JS validation, not mine. I'd like to just use JS validation (on the left) and stop the browser's - which is why I thought novalidate was the ticket. How do I turn off the brower's, if not with no validate?

Comment: Rather than trying to turn off browser validation, I suggest to try get the javascript validation to check that the input is a valid email address. Whether it's by getting the Silverstripe javascript to work, or blocking that javascript and using your own javascript validator.

Answer (score 2):

In SilverStripe 3.0/1 it enabled the use of the HTML5 required attributes which web browsers pick up and do their own validation for (which you've seen).

If you want to stop the browser behaviour remove the required attribute from the markup SilverStripe provides

```
TextField::create('MyTextField')->setAttribute('required', false)
```

This will still make the form field required in the PHP validation but disable the browser popup.